# Login as root in shell

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm trying to login as root in shell by following command :

```
$ echo 'myPassword' | sudo -Si
```

But gets me following error:

```
stdin: is not a tty
-bash: line 1: myPassword: command not found
```

**My Goal :**

I added above command in `~/.bashrc` in order to whenever Terminal starts up, it logged in as root

**P.S :**

I can successfully run below command :

**For instance**

```
$ echo 'myPassword' | sudo -S chown $USER ~/file.txt
```

Comment: you don't need `i` flag here

Comment: As I said, I need `i` flag because I need to login as root

Comment: id you want to login as root use `sudo -S su -`

Comment: But, I need to get user password from echo output (echo 'myPassword') ...

Comment: bug reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xen-3.1/+bug/1167281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
sudo -i
```

**Update:**

Seems like you want to get into root automatically whenever terminal is opened. Well, I'm not going to give you a lesson about security, but instead will provide you a solution:

1. Get rid of password when doing `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```

   And add following line (replace *username* with whatever you need):

   ```
   username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```
2. Next, add following at the end of your *~/.bashrc* file:

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```

Comment: See `My Goal` section in the first post

Comment: I don't want to get rid of password entry for everytime I execute `sudo -i`. I just want to login as root (i.e. `sudo -i`) without needing to enter it while loading terminal. Look at this code:
`echo 'myPassword' | sudo -S chown $USER ~/file.txt`
This one is successfully executed but now look at this:
`echo 'myPassword' | sudo -S -i`
Now I receive the mentioned error (stdin: is not a tty)

Comment: My answer does *exactly* whay you want, as described in your question. Furthermore, this is contradictory what you have asked: you want to get into root on every terminal start, but you want to keep password for `sudo` for particular user? What is the reason of having the password for `sudo`, if the terminal will always be in root anyways?

Comment: Furthermore, it's already second time when you are stating additional conditions for your question. Stop doing that and mention everything you want in your question! Otherwise, how the hell people can guess what's in your head?

Comment: Why do people always recommend `sudo su`? It makes no sense, it is redundant and adds (a negligible) overhead. Just use `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` instead.